# I cannot create a multiple instances on mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to run multiple instances of MySQL 5.7.13 under Ubuntu 14.04 x64 but when so I created a new group in my.cnf called [mysqld1] and run the following command but unfortunately I get this error message:

```
    mbnoimivm@ubuntu:~$ sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql1
    [sudo] password for mbnoimivm:
    2016-07-29 21:12:27 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqld --initialize
    2016-07-29 21:12:27 [ERROR]   Can't locate the server executable (mysqld).
    mbnoimivm@ubuntu:~$ sudo service mysql status
     * MySQL Community Server 5.7.13 is running
    mbnoimivm@ubuntu:~$
```

How can I fix this issue?

Config file

--- my.cnf ---

```
    [client]

    port        = 3306

    socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

    default-character-set = utf8


    [mysqld_safe]

    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

    socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

    nice        = 0


    [mysqld]

    user        = mysql


    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

    socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

    port = 3306

    basedir        = /usr

    datadir = /var/lib/mysql

    tmpdir        = /tmp

    lc-messages-dir    = /usr/share/mysql

    explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

    collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

    init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'

    character-set-server = utf8

    key_buffer_size = 384M

    max_allowed_packet = 128M

    table_open_cache = 512

    sort_buffer_size = 2M

    read_buffer_size = 2M

    read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M

    myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M

    thread_cache_size = 8

    query_cache_size = 256M

    log-error    = /var/log/mysql/error.log

    symbolic-links=0

    big-tables

    default-storage-engine = MyISAM

    sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

    slow-query-log = 1

    slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/slow.log

    general-log = 1

    general-log-file = /var/log/mysql/general.log


    [mysqld1]
    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.pid

    socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld1.sock

    port        = 3307

    user        = mysql

    basedir        = /usr

    datadir = /var/lib/mysql1


    [mysqldump]
    quick

    max_allowed_packet = 16M


    [mysql]
    default-character-set = utf8

    no-auto-rehash


    [myisamchk]
    key_buffer_size = 256M

    sort_buffer_size = 256M

    read_buffer = 2M

    write_buffer = 2M


    [mysqlhotcopy]
    interactive-timeout


    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation of the MySQL server involves roughly three steps: 1) unpacking the software; 2) creating a default database; 3) creating a default user/password (and storing this in the database).

Should you accidentally lose the database files (usually located in /var/lib/mysql) then you can start again without completely reinstalling the server package. This is done with the command mysqld --initialize. If you run this command while a database is already in place, it will report an error ("File exists") and it won't attempt to overwrite the database. However, if you're unsure if the installation procedure has completed correctly, it's OK to delete the directory /var/lib/mysql and re-initialize the database.

The --initialize flag will cause MySQL to generate a root user and a random password, which is then written to the log file. For more information, see man mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I used the `apt-get install mysql-server-5.7` command to install in Ubuntu 18.0.4 and wasted more than 6 hours for troubshooting. I can not use `mysqld --initialize` command to initialize the instance datadir with the errors 'Cannot create directory' or 'Permission denied', until I have downloaded the **new bundle of MySQL**.

I choose the generic Linux version 5.7.32, you can [direct download by click the link.](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/23/file/mysql-5.7.32-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.gz)